# bios beeps codes

Tags: bios

I have a computer with a GF7050V-se mainboard but i get some beeps. There are 2 short beeps and 8-9-10 long beeps. Does anyone know what those beeps means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**﻿Boot Block Beep Codes**

Nbr of Beeps / Description

1    /   No media present. (Insert diskette inf loppy drive A:)

2 / “AMIBOOT.ROM” f ile not f ound in root directory of diskette in A:

3 / Insert next diskette if multiple diskettes are usedf or recovery

4 / Flash Programming successful

5 / File read error

7 / No Flash EPROM detected

10 / Flash Erase error

11 / Flash Program error

12 / “AMIBOOT.ROM” f ile size error

13 / BIOS ROM image mismatch (file layout does not match image present inf lash device)

**POST BIOS Beep Codes**

Number of Beeps /Description

1 / Memory ref resh timer error

3 / Base memory read/write test error

6 / Key board controller BAT command failed

7 / General exception error (processor exception interrupt error)

8 / Display memory error (system video adapter)

**Troubleshooting POST BIOS Beep Codes**

Number of Beeps / Troubleshooting Action

1, 3 / Reseat the memory, or replace with known good modules.

6, 7 / Fatal error indicating a serious problem with the system. Consult y our system manufacturer. Bef ore declaring the motherboard beyond all hope, eliminate the possibility of interf erence by a malf unctioning add-in card. Remov e all expansion cards except thev ideo adapter. • If beep codes are generated when all other expansion cards are absent, consult y our system manufacturer’s technical support. • If beep codes are not generated when all other expansion cards are absent, one of the add-in cards is causing the malf unction. Insert the cards back into the system one at a time until the problem happens again. This will rev eal the malf unctioning card.

8  / If the system video adapter is an add-in card, replace or reseat the video adapter. If thev ideo adapter is an integrated part of the sy stem board, the board may be faulty.

source : [your motherboard manual](http://www.biostar-usa.com/app/en-us/mb/content.php?S_ID=356)

Comment: So the problem is [“AMIBOOT.ROM” file not found in root directory of diskette in A:] ? Methinks not.

Answer (score 0):

If I googled it right, your should be AWARD bios. After googling on: "award bios beep codes" it comes out as some kind of memory problem (RAM).

Comment: I found an article that said : "because of the wide variety of different computer manufacturers with this BIOS, the beep codes may vary".

Comment: Yes, I googled on the motherboard model first. The version of bios afterwards.

Comment: Should have included a link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 99% of the time beep codes mean CPU or Memory.

The first thing I would always you do is to reseat the memory, if no change, take out all pci / addon cards, then try again. If still nothing, check the CPU is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Computerhope site has good information about [BIOS codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm). And the list is separated as per manufacturer. There are many other manufacturer. You've to find out which BIOS you've with your motherboard manual. Or you can try applications like CPU-Z Or PC-Wizard.